# onmouseover is overridding a:hover in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Background**: I am not sure what is going on, but I have a link that has an `a:hover` associated with it in the CSS. I also have an image that when the user rolls over that same link of text should also change color. If the user mouses over the link text first it changes color no problem. but as soon as they mouse over the image it still changes colors but the mouse over the text no longer works.

**Question:** Could the JavaScript associated with the `onmouseover`/`onmouseout` cancel out the CSS `a:hover` effect?

**Code outlined below:**

```
    <style type="text/css">
        a.cat_cartridge{
            text-decoration:none;
            color:#e77504;
            font:bold 12px arial;
        }

        a.cat_cartridge:hover {
            color:#cd1c1f;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
    </style>

     <div class="image-holder" style="width:150px;margin:0px auto;">
<a href="http://dev-store.url.com/product/serta-gel-king-title-/p810093914?pos=1:14&amp;Ntt=Mattresses">
    <img onmouseout="document.getElementById('mattresses_link').style.color='#e77504';" onmouseover="document.getElementById('mattresses_link').style.color='#cd1c1f';" src="http://qa-store.url.com/images/marketing/2016/091616-homepage-icon-mattresses.jpg" style="width:150px;height:150px;" />
    </a>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom-copy">
         <h3 style="text-align:center;">
             <a class="cat_cartridge" href="http://dev-store.url.com/product/serta-gel-king-title-/p810093914?pos=1:14&amp;Ntt=Mattresses" id="mattresses_link">Mattresses</a>
         </h3>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why use script for hover?

Comment: Did you figure it out? Take a look at my snippet below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could the JavaScript associated with the `onmouseover/onmouseout`
>   cancel out the CSS a:hover effect?

[Yes](https://jsfiddle.net/lustoykov/mzufe81w/2/)

```js
$( "div" ).mouseover(function() {
   // uncomment and run again to see how mouseover overrides hover
  // $("div").css({ 'background-color' : 'white'})
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  
}

div:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: While true in your example, OP has both mosueover and mouseout functions present. By adding to your code what OP would already have, presents no issues. `$( "div" ).mouseout(function() {
  $("div").css({ 'background-color' : 'red'}) 
});`

Answer (score 1):

You have a stray `</div>` tag at the end of the first `<a>` element which is causing this issue. Removing this will solve the problem. Amended markup:

```
<a href="http://dev-store.url.com/product/serta-gel-king-title-/p810093914?pos=1:14&amp;Ntt=Mattresses">        <img onmouseout="document.getElementById('mattresses_link').style.color='#e77504';" onmouseover="document.getElementById('mattresses_link').style.color='#cd1c1f';" src="http://qa-store.url.com/images/marketing/2016/091616-homepage-icon-mattresses.jpg" style="width:150px;height:150px;" /></a>

<div class="bottom-copy">
  <h3 style="text-align:center;">
    <a class="cat_cartridge" href="http://dev-store.url.com/product/serta-gel-king-title-/p810093914?           pos=1:14&amp;Ntt=Mattresses" id="mattresses_link">
      Mattresses
    </a>
  </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I updated my code there was a missing <div class="image-holder" style="width:150px;margin:0px auto;"> that I left out. Good catch. Thanks.

Comment: Ah okay, no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` from HTML and simply add this to CSS

```
    .image-holder:hover a.cat_cartridge{
        color:#cd1c1f;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
```

```html
    <style type="text/css">
        a.cat_cartridge{
            text-decoration:none;
            color:#e77504;
            font:bold 12px arial;
        }

        a.cat_cartridge:hover {
            color:#cd1c1f;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .image-holder:hover a.cat_cartridge{
            color:#cd1c1f;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
    </style>

     <div class="image-holder" style="width:150px;margin:0px auto;">
<a href="http://dev-store.url.com/product/serta-gel-king-title-/p810093914?pos=1:14&amp;Ntt=Mattresses">
    <img src="http://qa-store.url.com/images/marketing/2016/091616-homepage-icon-mattresses.jpg" style="width:150px;height:150px;" />
    </a>
    

    <div class="bottom-copy">
         <h3 style="text-align:center;">
             <a class="cat_cartridge" href="http://dev-store.url.com/product/serta-gel-king-title-/p810093914?pos=1:14&amp;Ntt=Mattresses" id="mattresses_link">Mattresses</a>
         </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```